# Displaying last state of application on startup?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

According iPhone application programmer guide, an application should load with the state it was in when last quit.

This requirement surely brings better usability but also requires some coding effort...

My question is: since iPhone OS 4.0 is released and is keeping last application state automatically, is this effort really justified or needed as for today?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't keep your application state. It keep it in background when you tap home button. But user can close it or system can close your application. So it will be better to keep last state anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That's make perfect sense.

However, I looked at the iPhone contacts and calendar built-in apps and they behave differently in this context...
- contact app do not display the last opened contact (instead, it displayes just contact list) 
- where calendar app always displays last opened event.

Any idea, why these apps behave differently? Are there any guidelines I should follow in my app implementation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Apps in the background in iOS4 can still be terminated without warning.